# Joining dataframes dplyr - error Error in is_character(x, n = 0L) : object 'Uuid' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

When trying to join two separate dataframes i get the following error

> Error in is_character(x, n = 0L) : object 'Uuid' not found.

I am trying to join the two following data frames on the column Uuid.

[Dateframe x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUWkD.png)
[Dateframe y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LodxM.png)

I use the following code after installing and loading the dplyr library

```
Dataframe <- left_join(x, y, by=Uuid)
```

I can't understand what is happening. Both variables are called Uuid in both dataframes and are of the character data type.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

I tried to join the dataframes using left_join in dplyr. I have doubled checked the names and that the Uuid are character type in both dataframes.

Comment: provide the column name as a string, so use quotes like this `left_join(x, y, by = "Uuid")`

Comment: In future, a `dput()` of your data is preferred, rather than an image. Makes answering questions much easier. Thanks